# Filter field does not work

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have created a lookup field which filter the data on a form, but after I  do the first selection it filters the data on grid and then the field goes non editable.

I have tried clearRanges, I have done the research and refresh after the executeQuery call at modified method.

I have 2 queryBuildDataSources:

```
public void executeQuery() 
{ 
     QueryBuildDataSource qbds1 = this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesLine)); 
     QueryBuildDataSource qbds2 = qbds1.addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));  
     qbds2.fetchMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin); 
     qbds2.relations(TRUE); 
     qbds2.clearRange(fieldNum(InventTable, field1)); 
     if (field.valueStr())                     
         qbds2.addRange(fieldNum(InventTable,field1)).value(queryvalue(field.valueStr()))‌​;
     super();
}
```

It doesn't work, why not?

Comment: Do you have any sample code you can provide to debug?

Comment: Can you edit your answer and format it?

Comment: `public void executeQuery() 
 
{  QueryBuildDataSource qbds1;      
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds2;   
    qbds1 = this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesLine)); 
    qbds2 = qbds1.addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));    qbds2.fetchMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin); 
qbds2.relations(TRUE); qbds2.clearRange(fieldNum(InventTable, field1));
   if(field.valueStr())
{         qbds2.addRange(fieldNum(InventTable,field1)).value(queryvalue(field.valueStr())); super()`

Comment: The Query is fine but I understood that modified method of string edit is not called,and I do not understand why.The lookup method of this string edit also is correct.

Comment: Is the lookup field linked to any fields of the data sources? Is there any code in your form that enables/disables controls, data sources or fields? Try to remove as much functionality, data sources and controls from the form as possible (or test with a duplicate). If this does not give you any hints, try to build a .xpo of your form that you can link here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you add the relation each time the form calls `executeQuery`.

To make it work it should read:

```
public void init() 
{ 
     QueryBuildDataSource qbds2;
     super();
     qbds2 = this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesLine)).addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));  
     qbds2.fetchMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin); 
     qbds2.relations(true); 
}

public void executeQuery() 
{ 
     QueryBuildDataSource qbds2 = qbds1.dataSourceTable(tableNum(InventTable));  
     SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds2, fieldNum(InventTable,field1)).value(queryvalue(field.text()))‌​;
     qbds2.enabled(field.text() != '');
     super();
}
```

The `InventTable` relations is added only once: in the `init` method of `SalesLine`.
Also the join mode should be `ExistsJoin`as you do not need any fields from `InventTable`.

The range is added only once (using `findOrCreateRange`) and the `InventTable` exist join is enabled only when the field control has data.